# What is the purpose of the 'Disciplined' badge?

Tags: support

I was browsing through the [Badges page](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges) when I came across this one under "Moderation Badges".

> "Disciplined" : Delete own post with score of 3 or higher

I do not understand the purpose of this badge. If a question or an answer has been upvoted at least 3 times, it mean to me that it has been useful post (and it will probably be useful in the future too).

What is the explanation and some example case of the purpose of this badge ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might answer something with a good answer (that people vote for) that doesn't actually answer the question. That might be because the question wasn't originally clear and the assumption you make in your answer turns out not to be correct, or something else changes, or you just misread it. It happens.

Whatever the method, deleting the answer might be the Right Thing™ to do, but it means you'll lose reputation. The badge is awarded as a reward for your honesty.

Please don't delete a good answer (that does answer the question) just to get the badge.

Comment: This always confused me. Thanks.