# What is the score of a question?

Tags: support

Can you explain what is the score of a question and how can I understand what is the score of a question?

Comment: Are you just looking for this? https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: In the site is said that, if you delete a question with the score of 3 or more you will get a badge. What does it mean by a question with the score of three or more?                                                                                            https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14364/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-disciplined-badge

Comment: The question must have three or more upvotes, than it does downvotes, the "score" is the number left of the question, it must be, at least +3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The score of a post is the sum of votes on it.

When someone* clicks the up arrow on a post (upvotes it) that increases its score by one.

When someone** clicks the down arrow on a post (downvotes it) that decreases its score by one.

This post has a score of 98:

[image: post score is 98]

When you have 1000 reputation points, you gain the ability to see the score breakdown by clicking on the score:

[image: post score is 99-1]

---

<sub>* this applies when the person voting has at least 15 reputation; otherwise the vote is *anonymous****.

** this applied when the person voting has at least 125 reputation; otherwise the vote is *anonymous****.

*** *anonymous votes* are recorded and information about them can be found, for example in the [public data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/), but it does not affect the post score.</sub>

Comment: Do _anonymous_ votes become normal votes when a user passes the 15/125 rep mark?

Comment: @Dan no. [Possibly of interest on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84584/buffered-voting)